# Show hide multiple divs

Tags: jquery, click, toggle, show-hide

The idea was, that when I click on a pictire, another picture and some text woul show. This I have succeded with:

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();

$('.show_hide').click(function(){
$(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
});

});
```

HTML

```
  <a href="#" class="show_hide"
   ><img src="images/owl.png" id="owl" width="200" height="200"  alt="owl"></a>


  <div class="slidingDiv">
  Philip to the rescue!! <img src="images/cola.jpg"
     width="256" height="320" alt="cola  Philip">
  <a href="#" class="show_hide">Hide</a></div>
```

CSS

```
.slidingDiv {
   height:300px;
   padding:20px;
   margin-top:10px;
}

.show_hide {
   display:none;
}
```

But I'm a bit confused on how I can do this with more than one picture?

If I for an example had, 8 different clickable images, that would show 8 different images and texts.

And, is there any way of making it go up instead of down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An elegant solution is to wrap the toggling link and the toggled content like this:

```
<div class="toggler-wrap">
    <a href="#" class="toggler">Toggle content</a>
    <div class="content">This text can be toggled.</div>
</div>
```

Then you could toggle any content div with this code:

```
$(function(){
    $('.toggler').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().find('.content').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/TW5Eq/ for an example!
Have fun practicing!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a data attribute to abstract the class name:

```
<a href="#" data-target="someclass" class="show_hide">

$('.show_hide').click(function(){
     var myClass=$(this).attr('data-target');
     $("."+myClass).slideToggle();
}
```